# Double Cookie (CSRF + Cookie) Spring Cloud Gateway for Microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I am currently working on Spring Boot Microservice application. I want to have two
options to protect the same microservice.

1. Route protected with JWT for mobile native apps. (This is already done)
2. Route protected with Double Cookie for SPA (Reactjs)

The current structure that I have.

1. API Gateway - In this I have created JwtAuthFilter mentioned below and this works as expected. In this, I have added the logic to validate the JWT Token and kept the secret key in this project but the token is not generated from API Gateway but is generated from Identity Microservice mentioned in point 2. This uses the following package `spring-cloud-starter-gateway`

`public class JwtAuthFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory`

2. Identity Microservice - In this, I have added the spring-boot-starter-security package and generated the token from this project only. API Gateway calls the identity service and shares the token with the client.

**Now the Problem**

I want to use Double Cookie to secure the SPA and not JWT. What I have understood is that I can add Globalcors like this in API Gateway:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
           allowedOrigins: "*"
           allowedMethods: "*"
           allowedHeaders: "*"
```

But how to handle the `cors()` as it is mentioned in Identity Service. I can create the csrf API in identity service and share back the csrf with SPA via API Gateway but how to validate this csrf for the next set of requests before routing to the microservice at API Gateway only like the same as JWT which is being validated at API Gateway.

Also, both JWT and Double Cookie should work for same route

JwtAuthFilter

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=service-1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://service-1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/service1/*
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=JwtAuthFilter
```

Thanks in advance